# SerialPort Performance

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I want to transfer data between an Atmega168 via RS232 cable to my pc for editing! But the Atmega is too fast to handle for the SerialPort.DataReceived Event. Is there a proposal or a instruction how to speed up serialport or use an unmanaged serialport?

Also the existing code which is not working it just add entries to a list (of strings)

```
 Private Sub Me_DataReceived() Handles Me.DataReceived
    DataLines.Add(Me.ReadLine().Trim)
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of handshaking are you using? Xon/Xoff, RTS/CTS or none?

Comment: none... should i change handshake???

Comment: If you use none, the sending device will continue dumping data to your program causing dataloss. If you use handshaking you will need to set it up on both devices, plus if you use RTS/CTS you will need to change your serial cable also. Your only other option would to  be to slow down the baud rate to a point that you are no longer dropping data.

Comment: but my problem is not that i am dropping data! is that the data comes too fast for the serialport.datareceived event to handle. Think that i have 40% cpu load! but i don't drop any data cause i add the incoming lines in a list(of string). Any other proposal in serialport perfomance?

Comment: Are the baud rates and the parity setup the same? The serialport class runs in its own thread, what handshaking will do is stop your stream of data until the buffer gets empty and then restart it. It the data doesn't get to your data received event it is effectivly being dropped.

Comment: This is a debugger artifact in vb.net.  Try again without the debugger.

Comment: I have serial ports working with no problems at 115200 with 'streaming' data. I guess your problem lies in data handler. Adding lines to a list is a very slow procedure. Also, as Hans said: applications in VB.NET tend to run much slower while debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but please provide a more accurate way of handling 150 lines per second... I want to update 4 directx graphs and one richtextbox and one listview! i simply can't finde the right pattern to all that and at the same keep up with Atmega! as much for debugger artifact yeah that's true the cpu load only for the graphs is 30% but i can't figure out how to update winform controls and keep up with the Atmega... Please some help would be more than appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once and solved it by adding a short piece of C++ code that reads data from the serial port to my project and then adding a reference to that library in my C# project.  The C++ code ran more than 10 times faster.  What bit rate are you using?